# MySQL Insert if not exists

Tags: mysql, insert, not-exists

I'm struggling with MySQL.
I want to insert some values in a table, but only if these values don't exist already.

Ex :

```
INSERT INTO subnets (subnet,mask,sectionId,description)
SELECT * FROM (SELECT '174399232','24','1','VlanTest') AS tmp
WHERE NOT EXISTS ( SELECT subnet FROM subnets WHERE subnet = '174399232') LIMIT 1;
```

The fact is I'm having the following error :

```
#1060 - Duplicate column name '1'
```

I can't use the "INSERT IGNORE INTO" because there is no unique field, and any of them can be unique. Indeed, there are several "subnet" with the same value (0) and it can't be changed, so it can't be unique. Moreover, the primary key is in auto_increment mode so it can't be used as a "key".

The MySQL version I'm running is 5.5.57.

Can you please help me ? thanks.

Comment: I am pretty sure, there is something missing here because above sql should run perfectly if your subnets table schema is (id, subnet, mask, sectionId, description) and you are not using join in `( select ...) as tmp` part of query. Still for safer side, you can go ahead and give alias in 2nd row `(select '174399232' as a,'24' as b,'1' as c,'VlanTest' as d)` and try it out.

Comment: Hi greperror,
Thank you very much for your answer! Apparently, it worked great !
But would you be able to explain me what was wrong .. ?

Comment: Your welcome, even I am unsure what is exactly wrong(probably whatever it is a problem for specific MySQL version, or specific record), the solution was just a hack to fool the MySQL, the error was `Duplicate column name '1'` , which indicates that the column name you had in the the 2nd row of query `(SELECT ....., '1', .....) as tmp` is clashing with some other column named '1' too. So, I believe the record which might be failing for you, is when 2 of the columns (probably mask and sectionId) have same value '1'. By giving different alias names, b and c, it is resolved.

Comment: Thank you very much, that was pretty clear and sounds now obvious.
By the way, do you have an idea of how inserting multiple values ?
I'd like to insert about 9 rows, do you think I'll have to repeat this query 9 times ? 

Thanks again

Comment: If it is just 9 times, you can very well get done with it by writing 9 insert queries one after other and running it in one shot. If it is a regular process, and can be for much more number of records, you can try any scripting language as python for it, which read records from file in a batch and run a batch insert query.

Comment: That is perfect. I just added these queries in my python script which generates the final SQL query that will be implemented in my software.
Thank you very much for your advices, that was really clear.